# List all employee's names and their managers by manager name using an inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is my CREATE TABLE script:

```
create table EMPLOYEES
    (EmpID    char(4)         unique Not null,
     Ename    varchar(10),
     Job      varchar(9),
     MGR      char(4),
     Hiredate date,
     Salary   decimal(7,2),
     Comm     decimal(7,2),
     DeptNo   char(2)         not null,
         Primary key(EmpID),
         Foreign key(DeptNo) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS(DeptNo));
```

The following is my INSERT script:

```
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7839,'King','President',null,'17-Nov-11',5000,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7698,'Blake','Manager',7839,'01-May-11',2850,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7782,'Clark','Manager',7839,'02-Jun-11',2450,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7566,'Jones','Manager',7839,'02-Apr-11',2975,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7654,'Martin','Salesman',7698,'28-Feb-12',1250,1400,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7499,'Allen','Salesman',7698,'20-Feb-11',1600,300,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7844,'Turner','Salesman',7698,'08-Sep-11',1500,0,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7900,'James','Clerk',7698,'22-Feb-12',950,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7521,'Ward','Salesman',7698,'22-Feb-12',1250,500,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7902,'Ford','Analyst',7566,'03-Dec-11',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7369,'Smith','Clerk',7902,'17-Dec-10',800,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7788,'Scott','Analyst',7566,'09-Dec-12',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7876,'Adams','Clerk',7788,'12-Jan-10',1100,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7934,'Miller','Clerk',7782,'23-Jan-12',1300,null,10);
```

The following is my SELECT script:

```
select distinct e.Ename as Employee, m.mgr as reports_to
from EMPLOYEES e
inner join Employees m on e.mgr = m.mgr;
```

Im getting the employees with their corresponding manager's ID;

```
Ford    7566
Scott   7566
Allen   7698
James   7698
Martin  7698
Turner  7698
Ward    7698
Miller  7782
Adams   7788
Blake   7839
Clark   7839
Jones   7839
Smith   7902
```

*How do I list the manager name as well?*
*Am I doing the right inner join?*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `m.Ename` to your `SELECT` query:

```
select distinct e.Ename as Employee, m.mgr as reports_to, m.Ename as Manager
from EMPLOYEES e
inner join Employees m on e.mgr = m.EmpID;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the last script I had to write.  Ive been righting sql scripts for the past 5 hours.  I can go to sleep now.  I was confusing myself because my brain needs a rest.  I would upvote you but I dont have 15 reputation yet.  I can accept your answer.  VERY HELPFUL!  :)

Comment: How can I achieve this using lambda expression in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is close you need to join using the `mgr` and the `empid`

```
on e1.mgr = e2.empid
```

So the full query is:

```
select e1.ename Emp,
  e2.eName Mgr
from employees e1
inner join employees e2
  on e1.mgr = e2.empid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b546d/2)

If you want to return all rows including those without a manager then you would change it to a `LEFT JOIN` (for example the president):

```
select e1.ename Emp,
  e2.eName Mgr
from employees e1
left join employees e2
  on e1.mgr = e2.empid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b546d/3)

The president in your sample data will return a `null` value for the manager because they do not have a manager.

Answer (score 1):

No, the correct join is:

```
inner join Employees m on e.mgr = m.EmpID;
```

You need to match the ManagerID for the current employee with the EmployeeID of the manager. Not with the ManagerID of the manager.

**update**
As noted by Andrey Gordeev:
You'd also need to add `m.Ename` to your `SELECT` query in order to get the name of the Manager in your result. Otherwise you'd only get the managerID.

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect `ON` clause at the join, this works:

```
inner join Employees m on e.mgr = m.EmpId;
```

The `mgr`  column references the `EmpId` column.

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a122/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.empno,a.ename,a.job,a.mgr,B.empno,B.ename as MGR_name, B.job as MGR_JOB from 
    emp a, emp B where a.mgr=B.empno ;
```

Comment: You may want to tell Jeff how and why this works, and not just post plain code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.Ename AS Employee, 
    m.mgr AS reports_to, 
    m.Ename AS manager 
FROM Employees e, Employees m 
WHERE e.mgr=m.EmpID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.ename as Employee, m.ename as Manager
from emp e, emp m
where e.mgr = m.empno
```

If you want to get the result for all the records (irrespective of whether they report to anyone or not), append (+) on the second table's name

```
select e.ename as Employee, m.ename as Manager
from emp e, emp m
where e.mgr = m.empno(+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select e.lastname as employee ,m.lastname as manager
  from employees e,employees m
 where e.managerid=m.employyid(+)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three tables- Equities(coulmns: ID,ISIN) and Bond(coulmns: ID,ISIN). Third table Securities(coulmns: ID,ISIN) contains all data from Equities and Bond tables.
Write SQL queries to validate below:
(1) Securities table should contain all the data from Equities and Bonds tables. (2) Securities table should not contain any data other than present in Equities and Bonds tables

Comment: Please try to format your answer, providing an example and more context, Is really hard to understand what you mean, and if it is an answer to the PO question. [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.FirstName As "Employee Name", 
   M.FirstName AS "Manager"
     FROM Employee E
       INNER JOIN Employee M
         ON E.ID = M.ManagerID
         Order By E.FirstName;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

question:-.DISPLAY EMPLOYEE NAME , HIS DATE OF JOINING, HIS MANAGER NAME & HIS MANAGER'S DATE OF JOINING. 
 ANS:-
select e1.ename Emp,e1.hiredate,
   e2.eName Mgr,e2.hiredate
 from emp e1, emp e2
   where e1.mgr = e2.empno